# binding and castproblem. how do i cast a editText into a editable?

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, binding, android-edittext

Good evening, I have a problem with binding and editable.

```
binding.editText.text = String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + " : " + 
                        String.format("%02d", picker.minute) + "PM"
```

I know ".text" requires a editable, but how do i cast it?
I tried all type of normal casting but it seems not to be working.

The error disappears if i delete the "="

Answer (score 0):

Casting is the wrong word to describe it. Casting is promising the compiler that the object already is of another type. And a String is not an Editable, so casting it would cause a crash with ClassCastException. The correct question would be how to *convert* the String to an Editable.

But you don't need to anyway. The `text` property expects an Editable, but there is also a `setText` function that accepts any CharSequence, which includes String.

```
binding.editText.setText(
  String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + " : " + String.format("%02d", picker.minute) + "PM"
)
```

And a tip, you can use `format` as an extension function to make it more concise.

```
binding.editText.setText(
  "%02d".format(picker.hour - 12) + " : " + "%02d".format(picker.minute) + "PM"
)
```

And you can use string template format to make the concatenation more concise, too:

```
binding.editText.setText("${"%02d".format(picker.hour - 12)}:${"%02d".format(picker.minute)}PM")
```